# Cyborg Movie from the early 80's, possibly late 70's NOT Eliminators!

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's not Eliminators, I own it, I'm looking for a different one.

In this one a cyborg, unfortunately I can't remember much, it's him and a woman though at least, possibly a team, end up at one point in the woods, and one of his legs is screwed up, so he sits on a log and takes off his feet like boots, and attaches a little tank tread to the bottoms of his legs.

Again, NOT The Eliminators, this guy is literally standing on the Tank Treads like they are a Segway.

Comment: Are you sure it's not Eliminators?